# Algo falla en un modelo de Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Verán, he creado un modelo el cual sirve para enlazar un comentario a un usuario.

Este es el código models.py:

```
class mensajeria(models.Model):
    texto=RichTextField(max_length=300)
    usuario=models.OneToOneField(User)
    def __srt__(self):
        return self.usuario.username
```

En el administrador se debería ver quién es el usuario, pero por algún error no se muestra lo que tengo en la funcion `__srt__`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es muy extraño este error.

**Edito:** Tambien afecta esto al shell.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado: Por un momento logre hacer que se mostrase la tabla, pero ahora ocurre que me sale este error: no such table: ciencia_mensaje.
Parece que es un error debido a la clave foranea.

Comment: Intenta con `self.usuario.models.username` o prueba con `self.usuario.get_full_name`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es el nombre del método, es `__str__` (del inglés **String**) y no `__srt__`:

```
class mensajeria(models.Model):
    texto=RichTextField(max_length=300)
    usuario=models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username
```

Lo recomendable es usar el decorador [`python_2_unicode_compatible`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible) para que sea compatible en las versiones de Python 2.x y 3.x:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class mensajeria(models.Model):
    texto=RichTextField(max_length=300)
    usuario=models.OneToOneField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.usuario.username
```

Lo que hace esto es definir los métodos `__unicode__` y `__str__` para Python 2, para Python 3 solo basta con definir el método `__str__` como lo estás haciendo.

Comment: Ahora mi problema se ha agravado. Lo explicare todo en otro mensaje.